# How to pass object context to .on() callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, jquery-callback

I'm working on structuring my JavaScript by using the Module Pattern as explained [here](http://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/).

This is a very simplified version of my code:

```
var obj = {
  bindUIActions: function(){
    $('#button').on('click', {self: this}, this.doStuff);
  },
  doStuff: function(e){
    $(this).fadeOut();
    var self = e.data.self;
    self.doSomethingElse();
  },
  doSomethingElse: function(){
    //....
  }
}
```

I need to pass the object context to the doStuff method because I don't want to use:

```
obj.doSomethingElse();
```

So I can use the code again somewhere else, or change the object name ('obj') later on.
Using event data does not feel as the best solution, so is there a better way to get this done?

I've used $.proxy to change the context for the .on() callback function and that works. The problem is that I need to keep the this context from the click-element also, to get

```
$(this).fadeOut();
```

to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with using `obj.doSomethingElse();` or event data?  You are saying no to the "best" methods and then asking for the best method.

Comment: If you don't want the 2 methods that you've tried, then you can try passing the context as a variable to `doStuff()`, that's the only other option.  `var self = this;  $('#button').on('click', function(e){ self.doStuff.call(this, e, self); });`  Then you would have `function doStuff(e, context){`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! If I decide to change the name of the object during development, I'd have to change all occurences of the name - so I like to use a reference instead. For Event Data: I was curious if this is a 'good' option or that I missed a more common option. It works - I just like to learn to do it in a way that's most common to other developers.

Comment: The "event data" method is fine.  I see no issue with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could set the context with one of these:

- native: [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (js 1.8+)
- jquery function: [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/)
- third party libs as underscore: [_.bind](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#bind)